# Discrete event simulation for production defects

Tags: r, simulation

I have one machine, which produces parts. In `machine_failure_rate`% it produces faulty parts which need to be produced again. Thus, we end up with a simple queuing problem. Can the following code be futher functionalized? I have the feeling, I can get rid of `time_parts`, but all I have in mind deteriorates the code as I need further lookups in the `production_df` data frame to look for "what was produced / what needs to be produced now?". The following script is running:

```
input_rate <- 1/60 # input rate [1/min, 1/input_rate corresponds to interarrival time in min]
n <- 1000 # number of parts
dt <- 1 # timestep = time to transfer faulty parts back to production. [min]

machine_production_rate <- 1/40 # production rate [1/min]
machine_failure_rate <- 0.2 # machine failure rate


# Sum all interarrival times
set.seed(123456)
t_event <- cumsum(rpois(n, 1/input_rate))

# Create initial list of tasks. Produces parts will be cut off.
time_parts <- data.frame(id = c(1:n),
                         t = t_event,
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# ========= Functions ==========================================================
create_machine <- function(failure_rate, production_rate) {
  machine <- list()
  machine$failure_rate <- failure_rate
  machine$production_rate <- production_rate
  machine$is_occupied <- FALSE
  return(machine);
}

update_machine <- function(ind_production_df, machine, production_df) {
  if (machine$is_occupied) {
    if (production_df$po_start[ind_production_df] + 1/machine$production_rate <= t) {
      machine$is_occupied <- FALSE
    }
  }
  return(machine)
}

production_summary <- function(production_df, machine, input_rate) {
  no_of_failures <- sum(production_df$no_failures)
  total_production_time <- max(production_df$po_start) + 1/machine$production_rate
  uptime <- (no_of_failures + n)/machine$production_rate
  print(paste0("Estimated machine$failure_rate ", 
               round(no_of_failures/(no_of_failures + n), 2),
               " [theory ", round(machine$failure_rate, 2), "]"))
  print(paste0("Up-time ", uptime, 
               ", of total time ", total_production_time, ". Auslastung ",
               round(uptime/total_production_time, 2),
               " [theory ", round(input_rate/machine$production_rate*1/(1 - machine$failure_rate), 2), "]"))
}


# ========= DE simulation ======================================================
machine <- create_machine(machine_failure_rate, machine_production_rate)
production_df <- data.frame(id = time_parts$id,
                            time = time_parts$t,
                            production_start = rep(0, nrow(time_parts)),
                            no_failures = rep(0, nrow(time_parts)),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

t <- 0
while (length(time_parts$t) > 0) {
  ind_production_df <- which(production_df$id == time_parts$id[1])

  machine <- update_machine(ind_production_df, machine, production_df)

  if (!machine$is_occupied & time_parts$t[1] <= t) {
    # A machine is available and a part needs to be produced
    machine$is_occupied <- TRUE
    production_df$po_start[ind_production_df] <- t
    if (runif(1) < machine$failure_rate) {
      # bad part
      time_parts$t[1] <- time_parts$t[1] + dt
      time_parts <- time_parts[sort(time_parts$t, index.return = TRUE)$ix, ]

      production_df$no_failures[ind_production_df] <- 
        production_df$no_failures[ind_production_df] + 1
      t <- t + min(time_parts$t[1], dt)
    } else {
      # good part
      if (production_df$po_start[ind_production_df] + 1/machine$production_rate >= t &&
          nrow(time_parts) >= 2) {
        time_parts <- time_parts[2:(nrow(time_parts)), ]
      } else {
        time_parts <- time_parts[FALSE, ]
      }
      t <- t + 1/machine$production_rate
      machine$is_occupied <- FALSE
    }
  } else {
    # machine is occupied or no part needs to be produced
    t <- t + min(time_parts$t[1], dt)
  }
}


# ========= Results ============================================================
production_summary(production_df, machine, input_rate)
```

Backround: I think about a generalisation (more machines, more input-sources, more complex rules how/when/... parts a produces). I fear that I will end up with tons of unreadable and unmaintainable code-lines if I proceed like this.

---

**Edit**: I think `t <- t + min(time_parts$t[1], dt)` is a bug and the correct version is `t <- min(time_parts$t[1], t + dt)`. It only worked because the time difference `dt` was always the minimum. In the last case you could speed up using `t <- max(time_parts$t[1], t + dt)` as there is nothing to do in the time inbetween.

Comment: Could you explain what "po_start" represents - is this the time at which production starts for a given `part`?

Comment: Yes, it means, when the production really starts - due to a queue, this can be delayed in contrast to the original `t_event`. I also made a tiny edit to the post...

Comment: I've been working on this, but can't post my code from work. I can restructure the code and get the same result but I was wondering whether there might be an error. Within your code `t <- t + min(time_parts$t[1], dt)`. The contents of `time_parts` are the earliest-time a given part can be made and the current time must increase at each iteration, shouldn't you update current time to `max(t + dt, time_parts$t[1])`?

Comment: @RussHyde No, I don't think so: if I increase `t`, I should take the earliest point in time where something can change. This is save. It might be, that sometimes a `max` would speed up... I am curious about your results :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a pretty difficult challenge - principally because R doesn't have a built-in [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) data-structure, but also because the priority-queue-like data-frame (`time_parts`) was wrapped around the results-storing data-frame (`production_df`) and the main `while` loop contains code at a few different levels of abstraction.

## Idiomatic `R`

I did some simple stuff first: pulled all your functions to the start of the script, reformatted some code/comments.

There was a couple of things I changed for idiomatic reasons:

```
which(production_df$id == time_parts$id[1])
# -->
match(time_parts$id[1], production_df$id)

# time_parts[2:(nrow(time_parts)), ] # and
# time_parts[FALSE, ] # when time_parts has only one row
# can both be replaced with
time_parts[-1, ]
# (which is the idiomatic way to drop the first row) so this allowed us to remove an if-else clause

# You don't need to do rep(some_value, n) when you're adding a
# constant column to a data-frame at construction:
production_df <- data.frame(id = time_parts$id,
                            time = time_parts$t,
                            production_start = rep(0, nrow(time_parts)),
                            no_failures = rep(0, nrow(time_parts)),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# -->
production_df <- data.frame(id = time_parts$id,
                            time = time_parts$t,
                            production_start = 0,
                            no_failures = 0,
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# `order(...)` does the same thing as `sort(..., index.return)$ix`
sort(time_parts$t, index.return = TRUE)$ix
# -->
order(time_parts$t)

# `nrow(x)` is more idiomatic than `length(x$some_column)`
while(length(time_parts$t) > 0){ 
# -->
while(nrow(time_parts) > 0) {
# but I subsequently replaced this newer line as well
```

## Explicit data-classes

I converted your `create_machine` function so that it returns an object of class "Machine"; this wasn't really necessary.

```
create_machine <- function(failure_rate, production_rate) {
  structure(
    list(
      failure_rate = failure_rate,
      production_rate = production_rate,
      is_occupied = FALSE
    ),
    class = "Machine"
  )
}
```

I added a `create_part` function that similarly returns a `Part` object. There was a lot of repeats of `1 / machine$production_rate` in your code; I replaced these with a call to part$production_duration. Also I thought your test to see whether a produced part was a failure should be associated with the produced part object (`part$is_failure`); with this, the while-loop logic becomes more explicit:

```
create_part <- function(machine) {
  structure(
    list(
      is_failure = runif(1) < machine$failure_rate,
      production_duration = 1 / machine$production_rate
    ),
    class = "Part"
  )
}

# then we can use this in the while-loop
part <- create_part(machine)

if (part$is_failure) {
  # bad part logic
  ...
} else {
  # good part logic
  ...
}
```

## Restructuring the `while` loop

I wanted to push that while-loop into a function - the less work you do in the global environment, the better.

Since you want to extract data from `production_df` for your report, the function should return the `production_df`. During the while-loop, you access `production_df`, `time_parts`, `t`, `dt` (which I renamed `dt_recovery` based on your comments), `n` and `machine`.
So we might want to pass all of those into that function. But we can compute some of those from the others:

- `n` is the nrow of `production_df`,
- `t` isn't needed outside of the while loop and
- the data that initialises `time_parts` also initialises `production_df`.

The only thing we need to initialise both `time_parts` and `production_df` is the arrival-times or times at which the parts were ordered (which I renamed `t_ordered`).

So, we can put that while-loop into a function that takes arguments `t_ordered`, `dt_recovery`, `machine`.

```
run_event_simulation <- function(t_ordered, machine, dt_recovery) {
  n_parts <- length(t_ordered)

  # results data-frame
  production_df <- data.frame(
    id = seq(n_parts),
    t_ordered = t_ordered,
    t_started = 0,
    t_completed = 0,
    no_failures = 0,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  time_parts <- ... # define in terms of production_df

   # while-loop logic

   # return the updated production_df
```

I added the column `t_completed` into `production_df` so that you can more easily compute `total_production_time` from `production_df` in your report (this allows you to generalise the production rates)

```
# in `production_summary`
...
total_production_time <- max(production_df$t_completed)
...
```

## A functional priority queue

The really big step:

R doesn't have a native priority-queue, and it would be pretty hard to encode using the S3 or S4 classes since you can't update by reference in those classes. There is a priority-queue defined in the package `liqueueR`, but I've no experience of that. So I just wrote a simpler version of the priority queue (as an S3 class): this allows you to

- `peek`: extract the element in the queue with the lowest priority value (without mutating the queue)
- `delete_min`: remove that element with the lowest priority value from the queue and return the resulting queue
- `add`: add a new element to the queue according to it's priority, returning the resulting queue
- and provides a couple of helper methods (`is_empty`, `nrow`)

However, this doesn't provide a `pop_element(queue)`: typically, `pop_element` removes the leading element from the queue and returns that element. That is, it returns the leading element and updates the queue through a side-effect. This side-effect is problematic in R, so I didn't include a `pop_element` function. To achieve `pop_element` you have to `peek` and then `delete_min`.

```
# Priority Queue class

create_priority_queue <- function(x, priority_column) {
  structure(
    list(
      # note that we only `order` once - see `add` for how this is possible
      queue = x[order(x[[priority_column]]), ]
    ),
    class = "PriorityQueue",
    priority_column = priority_column
  )
}

# generic methods for Priority Queue
is_empty <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("is_empty")
peek <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("peek")
delete_min <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("delete_min")
add <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("add")
nrow <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("nrow")

nrow.default <- function(x, ...) {
  base::nrow(x)
}

# implemented methods for Priority Queue
nrow.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  nrow(x$queue)
}
is_empty.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  nrow(x) == 0
}
peek.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  x$queue[1, ]
}
delete_min.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  x$queue <- x$queue[-1, ]
  x
}
add.PriorityQueue <- function(x, new_element, ...) {
  priority_column <- attr(x, "priority_column")
  # split the existing values by comparison of their priorities to
  #  those of the new-element
  lhs <- which(x$queue[[priority_column]] <= new_element[[priority_column]])
  rhs <- setdiff(seq(nrow(x)), lhs)
  x$queue <- rbind(x$queue[lhs, ], new_element, x$queue[rhs, ])
  x
}
```

Then I replaced your `time_parts` data-frame with a PriorityQueue:

```
# inside run_event_simulation
...
  # Create initial list of tasks. Once produced, a part will be removed from the
  # queue.
  product_queue <- create_priority_queue(
    data.frame(
      id = production_df$id,
      t = production_df$t_ordered
    ),
    "t"
  )
...
```

I added a few other helpers. The final code looks like this:

```
# ---- classes

# Priority Queue class

create_priority_queue <- function(x, priority_column) {
  structure(
    list(
      queue = x[order(x[[priority_column]]), ]
    ),
    class = "PriorityQueue",
    priority_column = priority_column
  )
}

# A machine for producing `Part`s

create_machine <- function(failure_rate, production_rate) {
  structure(
    list(
      failure_rate = failure_rate,
      production_rate = production_rate,
      is_occupied = FALSE
    ),
    class = "Machine"
  )
}

# A manufactured part

create_part <- function(machine) {
  structure(
    list(
      is_failure = runif(1) < machine$failure_rate,
      production_duration = 1 / machine$production_rate
    ),
    class = "Part"
  )
}

# methods for Priority Queue

is_empty <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("is_empty")
peek <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("peek")
delete_min <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("delete_min")
add <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("add")
nrow <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("nrow")

nrow.default <- function(x, ...) {
  base::nrow(x)
}

nrow.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  nrow(x$queue)
}

is_empty.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  nrow(x) == 0
}

peek.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  x$queue[1, ]
}

delete_min.PriorityQueue <- function(x, ...) {
  x$queue <- x$queue[-1, ]
  x
}

add.PriorityQueue <- function(x, new_element, ...) {
  priority_column <- attr(x, "priority_column")
  lhs <- which(x$queue[[priority_column]] <= new_element[[priority_column]])
  rhs <- setdiff(seq(nrow(x)), lhs)
  x$queue <- rbind(x$queue[lhs, ], new_element, x$queue[rhs, ])
  x
}

# ---- functions

update_machine <- function(machine,
                           ind_production_df,
                           production_df,
                           current_time) {
  if (machine$is_occupied) {
    if (
      production_df$t_started[ind_production_df]
      + 1 / machine$production_rate <= current_time
    ) {
      machine$is_occupied <- FALSE
    }
  }
  return(machine)
}

should_produce_part <- function(machine,
                                earliest_production_time,
                                current_time) {
  !machine$is_occupied &&
    earliest_production_time <= current_time
}

increment_failures <- function(df, i) {
  df[i, "no_failures"] <- 1 + df[i, "no_failures"]
  df
}

# ---- format results

production_summary <- function(production_df, machine, input_rate) {
  n_parts <- nrow(production_df)
  no_of_failures <- sum(production_df$no_failures)
  total_production_time <- max(production_df$t_completed)
  uptime <- (no_of_failures + n_parts) / machine$production_rate
  print(paste0(
    "Estimated machine$failure_rate ",
    round(no_of_failures / (no_of_failures + n_parts), 2),
    " [theory ", round(machine$failure_rate, 2), "]"
  ))
  print(paste0(
    "Up-time ", uptime,
    ", of total time ", total_production_time, ". Auslastung ",
    round(uptime / total_production_time, 2),
    " [theory ",
    round(
      input_rate / machine$production_rate * 1 / (1 - machine$failure_rate), 2
    ),
    "]"
  ))
}


# ---- discrete-event simulation
#
run_event_simulation <- function(t_ordered, machine, dt_recovery) {
  n_parts <- length(t_ordered)

  # results data-frame
  production_df <- data.frame(
    id = seq(n_parts),
    t_ordered = t_ordered,
    t_started = 0,
    t_completed = 0,
    no_failures = 0,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  # Create initial list of tasks. Once produced, a part will be removed from the
  # queue.
  product_queue <- create_priority_queue(
    data.frame(
      id = production_df$id,
      t = production_df$t_ordered
    ),
    "t"
  )

  t <- 0
  while (!is_empty(product_queue)) {
    queued_part <- peek(product_queue)

    ind_production_df <- match(
      queued_part$id, production_df$id
    )

    machine <- update_machine(machine, ind_production_df, production_df, t)

    if (
      should_produce_part(machine,
                          earliest_production_time = queued_part$t,
                          current_time = t)
    ) {
      # A machine is available and a part needs to be produced

      # - pop the scheduled part from the queue; add it back if it's production
      # fails
      product_queue <- delete_min(product_queue)

      machine$is_occupied <- TRUE
      production_df$t_started[ind_production_df] <- t
      part <- create_part(machine)

      if (part$is_failure) {
        # bad part - add it back to the schedule
        queued_part$t <- queued_part$t + dt_recovery
        product_queue <- add(product_queue, queued_part)

        production_df <- increment_failures(production_df, ind_production_df)

        t <- t + min(peek(product_queue)$t, dt_recovery)
      } else {
        # good part
        t <- t + part$production_duration
        production_df$t_completed[ind_production_df] <- t
        machine$is_occupied <- FALSE
      }
    } else {
      # machine is occupied or no part needs to be produced
      t <- t + min(peek(product_queue)$t, dt_recovery)
    }
  }
  production_df
}

# ---- script
set.seed(123456)

# Input rate [1/min, 1/input_rate corresponds to interarrival time in min]
input_rate <- 1 / 60

# Number of parts
n_parts <- 1000

# timestep = time to transfer faulty parts back to production. [min]
dt_recovery <- 1

# Production rate [1/min]
machine_production_rate <- 1 / 40

# Machine failure rate
machine_failure_rate <- 0.2

# Sum all interarrival times
t_ordered <- cumsum(rpois(n_parts, 1 / input_rate))

machine <- create_machine(machine_failure_rate, machine_production_rate)

# ---- results

production_df <- run_event_simulation(
  t_ordered, machine, dt_recovery
)

production_summary(production_df, machine, input_rate)
```

---

Why aren't S3 queues easy?

(This is actually quite hard to explain). Well, the `pop` method on a priority-queue returns an element from the queue and moves the queue on by one step. (In R) Updating the queue might look like `new_queue <- old_queue[-1]` and obtaining the returned element might look like `returned_element <- old_queue[1]`. So a pop function might look like

```
pop <- function(q) {
  # extract the head
  el <- q[1]

  # In a reference-based language you could update the queue
  #  using a side-effect like `q.drop()`
  # But in R, this creates a new queue: and if it isn't returned 
  # explicitly, it is thrown away at the end of the `pop` function
  new_q <- q[-1]

  # return the element that's at the head of the original queue
  el
}

# calling_env
my_q <- create_queue(...)
my_head <- pop(my_q)
```

But the queue has not been altered by that `pop`. Now we could rewrite that function to do something dangerous like `q <<- q[-1]` and that would update the `q` in the calling environment. I consider this dangerous because `q` might not exist in the calling environment and that introduces side-effects, which are much harder to reason about.

Comment: @Christoph there was a couple of things I didn't feel comfortable restructuring. I couldn't work out why `update_machine` works the way it does: it seems to look into the future before it decides what to do now. It makes more sense to me for `is_occupied` to be set to FALSE at the end of each while-loop iteration.

Comment: @Christoph could you give some indication of whether you'd prefer to generalise the production-time (eg, replace the fixed production time with a Poisson-sampled time) or the number of machines

Comment: Updated. But it's pretty difficult to explain. I'm not particularly interested in stochastic simulation at present. I did have a look at your `simmer` documentation. Can you confirm that when you mclapply() over different simulation chains, different seeds are used for each chain?

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Unfortunately, simmer is not my package - so I can't answer your question. :-(

Comment: To your function `pop <- function(q)`: why don't you just `return(list(el=el, new_q=new_q)`?
Then you could work within one line `r <- pop(q); el <- r$el; q <- r$new_q; rm(r);`?
But I still understand your comment that calling by reference would be smart...

Comment: Because peek and delete_min provide that with fewer statements than your 4 lines in one line solution, in a way that imo requires less user overhead.